# Run code once in listview getitem

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented listview with custom adapter and with layout item.
In that i have a complex logic. 
when listview loads first it shows correct records with my logic. 
But when i scroll down and than up it changed my logic meaning and update data.

So i want to run that logic only once when listview bind..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In ListView scrolling can make items get recreated, if you implement your `getView` method incorrectly, it may have unwanted results. Please provide some code so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_cartcell_layout,
                null);
        holder.product_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        holder.base_price_tv = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.base_price_view);



        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    // here you can set your value to your view one example like below
            // if you have any arrylist then get your data and set to your view
            // for example "PRODUCTLIST" is your array list in which you store products
            // see how to set it

         if(PRODUCTLIST.get(position).getproductname !=null){

               holder.product_name.settext(PRODUCTLIST.get(position).getproductname);
              }

         if(PRODUCTLIST.get(position).getproductbaseprice !=null){

          holder.base_price_tv.settext(PRODUCTLIST.get(position).getproductbaseprice);

           }
        return convertView;
```